# Show a default image

Tags: post-thumbnails

Hello how can I do with this function if there is no post thumbnail loaded, show a default image

```
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'image' );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fallback default image when there is no featured image](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/336162/fallback-default-image-when-there-is-no-featured-image)

Answer (score 2):

Create "images" folder in current active theme the put "default-image.jpg" in that folder.

```
<?php  
if ( has_post_thumbnail( ) ) {
  echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'image' );
} else { ?>
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/images/default-image.jpg'; ?>"/>
<?php } ?>
```

Use path according to the theme (parent or child).

- [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri): url path to current Theme directory
- [`get_template_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/): url path to parent Theme directory